# Rename standard "edit" button in tableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I managed (with lots of trial and error) to have my tableview provide *only* reordering functionality, i.e. my tableview is editable but does not display "delete icons" nor indents the rows upon clicking on the edit button.

Now I would like the button to read "sort" instead of "edit".

I naively tried this:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title = @"Sort";
```

which works only once, i.e. it is correctly labeled "Sort", once clicked it renames to "Done", but then--as expected--it re-renames to "Edit".

In order to fix this, I deployed my "own" button on the navbar. This solution works--I can get the button to control the tableview editing mode, reload the data upon change, rename itself, etc--but I cannot get it to "stay highlighted", i.e. the default behaviour of the "Edit" button in a tableview.

Now my question is either:

a) Is there a way to rename (and keep it renamed, e.g. through a callback) the standard "Edit" button?

or

b) Is there a way to have a button behave "modally", i.e. stay selected, like the standard "Edit" button?

Thanks for any idea you might have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put your changes in the `- (void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated` method in your view controller.

```
- (void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    //Do super before, it will change the name of the editing button
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if (editing) {
      self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title = @"Done";
      self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleDone;
    }
    else {
      self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title = @"Sort";
      self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm (and answers my question). Thanks!